# Swift switch statement considered all cases of Int, but compiler still display error

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

I understand switch statement in Swift must be exhaustive, otherwise we have to provide an default case. I saw the code below online, the switch statement already have covered all cases in Int, but the compiler still display error message that switch must be exhaustive, consider adding a default clause. Is there something I'm missing?

```
extension Int {
    enum Kind {
        case Negative, Zero, Positive
    }

    var kind: Kind {
        switch self {
        case 0:
            return .Zero
        case let x where x > 0:
            return .Positive
        case let x where x < 0:
            return .Negative
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you needn't use the intermediate `x` variable in this case, as you can use pattern matching for anything (`_`) with an additional where clause, e.g. `case _ where self > 0: ...`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update for Swift 3:** Swift 3 introduced `ClosedRange` which makes
it possible to define a range like `1...Int.max` including the
largest possible integer (compare [Ranges in Swift 3](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/09/swift-3-ranges/)). So this compiles and works as expected,
but still requires a default case to satisfy the compiler:

```
extension Int {
    enum Kind {
        case negative, zero, positive
    }
    var kind: Kind {
        switch self {
        case 0:
            return .zero
        case 1...Int.max:
            return .positive
        case Int.min...(-1):
            return .negative
        default:
            fatalError("Oops, this should not happen")
        }
    }
}
```

There are other bug reports where the Swift compiler does not 
correctly determine the exhaustiveness of switch-statements, such
as https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-766, where Apple engineer Joe Groff
commented:

> Unfortunately, integer operations like '...' and '<' are just plain functions to Swift, so it'd be difficult to do this kind of analysis. Even with special case understanding of integer intervals, I think there are still cases in the full generality of pattern matching for which exhaustiveness matching would be undecidable. We may eventually be able to handle some cases, but there will always be special cases involved in doing so.

---

**Old answer:** The compiler is not so smart to recognize that you have covered
all possible cases. One possible solution is to add a default
case with a `fatalError()`:

```
var kind: Kind {
    switch self {
    case 0:
        return .Zero
    case let x where x > 0:
        return .Positive
    case let x where x < 0:
        return .Negative
    default:
        fatalError("Oops, this should not happen")
    }
}
```

Or make `case 0:` the default case:

```
var kind: Kind {
    switch self {
    case let x where x > 0:
        return .Positive
    case let x where x < 0:
        return .Negative
    default:
        return .Zero
    }
}
```

(*Remark:* I initially thought that the following would work correctly
without needed a default case:

```
var kind: Kind {
    switch self {
    case 0:
        return .Zero
    case 1 ... Int.max:
        return .Positive
    case Int.min ... -1:
        return .Negative
    }
}
```

However, this *compiles*, but aborts at runtime because you cannot
create the range `1 ... Int.max`. More information around this
problem can be found in the article [Ranges and Intervals in Swift](http://oleb.net/blog/2015/09/swift-ranges-and-intervals/).)

Comment: That's a really unfortunate limitation of ranges that you can't create one that goes up to the maximum value.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `case 1 ..< Int.max, Int.max:` just returns you to the compiler asking for a `default` case.

Comment: @vacawama: Yes, I had already tried that. And `case 0: / case 5 ... Int.max: / case Int.min ... -5:` compiles even though the cases are *not* exhaustive.

Comment: Wow.  Swift still has some rough edges apparently.

Comment: In light of limit case the above, could the internal storage of open ranges `[from,through]` as `from ..< through.successor()` (even if specified as `from ... through`) be seen as a limitation that should be prompted to the Swift team? Present, however, only for the limiting case when `through` equals the maximum value of the particular type (in which case `.successor()` overflows).

Comment: @dfri: Actually that seems to be a known restriction, I just found this: http://oleb.net/blog/2015/09/swift-ranges-and-intervals/: *"A `Range<Int>` can never contain `Int.max`."*, followed by possible solutions with custom operators (which still need the dummy `default` case!)

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a nice article, thanks! I though the author had it at `... as ClosedInterval`, but, alas, Swift couldn't interpret that the intervals were in fact exhaustive. Possibly this would be a more relevant prompt fur future Swift; cleverness of exhaustive pattern matching w.r.t. intervals (as seemingly works, from you answer above, at least so-so w.r.t. ranges).