# why `case self > 0: return .positive` is not allowed in switch statement

Tags: ios, swift, enums, switch-statement

I'm using swift and I have encountered an error when using switch statement and greater than > to compare a number.

Xcode display the following message: expression pattern of type "Bool" cannot match values of type "Int"

I know that by replacing `case self > 0: return .positive` with `case let x where x > 0: return .positive`, everything works just fine.

But I don't really understand why `case self > 0: return .positive` is not allowed? What is the reason behind it?

```
extension Int {
    enum Kind {
        case negative, zero, positive
    }
    var kind: Kind {
        switch self {
        case 0:
            return .zero
//Error: expression pattern of type "Bool" cannot match values of type "Int"
//        case self > 0:
//            return .positive
        case let x where x > 0: //this works
            return .positive
        default:
            return .negative
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: error message is telling you everything.  expression pattern of type "Bool" cannot match values of type "Int"

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975542/swift-2-expression-pattern-of-type-bool-cannot-match-values-of-type-int for a similar question.

Comment: In Swift 3 `case 1...Int.max:` would also work.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for all the helpful comment! i'm very honoured to be helped out by an swift expert :)

Comment: The "positive" case can also be checked with `case _ where self > 0:` – as mentioned in a comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476599/swift-switch-statement-considered-all-cases-of-int-but-compiler-still-display-e/36477188#comment60570202_36476599 to one of your older questions.

Comment: @MartinR Ah, that Q&A. W.r.t. the discussion in the comments to your answer there: it seems that even after the introduction of `ClosedRange`, the `switch` blocks are still unable to deduce that e.g. cases `Int.min...0` and `1...Int.max` are exhaustive (demaning a default case).

Comment: @dfri: Yes, I noticed that and have updated that part accordingly. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple rule about switch statements.

In each case of a switch statement, the expression that follows immediately after `case` is evaluated and compared to the thing that you are switching on.

So in your code, `self > 0` is evaluated and compared with `self`. Assuming `self` is 10,

```
self > 0 == self
true == 10 // WTF?
```

The second `case let x where x > 0` is different, `let x` is not an expression. It basically saying:

> In this `case`, I want a variable called `x` to be assigned the value of `self`. But please only do this if `x > 0` after doing the assignment. If `!(x > 0)`, go to another `case`.

Comment: thank you so much! that makes perfect sense! had a difficult time getting my head around this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Error message is telling you everything. expression pattern of type "Bool" cannot match values of type "Int".

```
case self > 0: // it will return Bool value but It needs to be a pattern against which the value can be matched
```

Comment: No, a case expression need not be a constant expression as you can see in `case let x where x > 0:`. It needs to be a *pattern* against which the value can be matched.

Comment: I agree. It needs to be a pattern against which the value can be matched.

Answer (score 1):

Since switch statements performs pattern matching, you needn't necessarily bind the value of self and test for inequality/equality for some case, but could modify your `positive` case for direct pattern matching of `self` to the range `1...Int.max`. E.g.

```
extension Int {
    enum Kind {
        case negative, zero, positive
    }
    var kind: Kind {
        switch self {
        case 0:
            return .zero
        case 1...Int.max:
            return .positive
        default:
            return .negative
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `case: 1...Int.max:` ? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124019/why-case-self-0-return-positive-is-not-allowed-in-switch-statement#comment67518701_40124019)

Comment: @MartinR Of course, thanks (for some reason I was stuck wanting to represent the open-closed range `(0, Int.max]`, satisfied with `[0, Int.max]` with guaranteed `0` exclusion, without considering the fact that we're working with integers). Missed that you'd already mentioned this in a comment to the Q!